# Buildfire: React Folder Plugin Template Error

Tags: reactjs, command-line-interface, buildfire

Trying to run reactFolderPluginTempalte in BuildfireSDK.

```
buildfire plugin clone reactFolderPluginTempalte
cd plugins/reactFolderPluginTempalte
npm install
npm audit fix
npm start (Change package.json to SET NODE_ENV for Windows)
cd..
cd..(get back to BuildfireSDK folder)
buildfire run 8082 (port set in webpack)
```

I get the error, (Cannot GET /control/content/index.html) for widget, content, settings.

How can I get this template working on Windows to start using the react templates?

Comment: Did you try using the default port at the last command?

Comment: Yes the default port is 3030 which also doesn't work